# how to trigger an event when consumer is defined in a separate class

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq

I'm a newbie to rabbitMQ. I'm trying to implement a simple queue where new messages trigger some logic in a tool I'm running. Right now I have defined the consumer in a separate class, and created an instance of the consumer class in my tool class. I'm not sure this is allowed. Currently, any time a message is received, it is printed to std.out. What I would like to happen is that any time a message is received, the method "do_something" is called with the message body as an input. What should I be doing in the callback method to make that happen?

```
class MyTool:

    def __init__(self):
        self.consumer=None

    def start_tool(self, some_input):
        queue_name = some_method(some_input)
        self.consumer = Consumer(queue_name)

    def do_something(self, queue_message):
        ... do things depending on content of queue_message
        return new_result

class Consumer:

    def __init__(self, queue_name):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name)

        channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=self.callback, auto_ack=True)

        print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
        channel.start_consuming()

    def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
        return body
```

Comment: Have you tried MyTool().do_something as callback function?

Comment: do_something is an instance method. If I call MyTool().do_something as the callback function, it does not know which instance of MyTool I would like to act on.

Comment: you can call do_something inside your callback function.

Comment: I must be missing something. I can't call this_tool_instance.do_something in the callback function, because the callback function doesn't know that this_tool_instance exists.